# React, Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working in react and basically I want to make an button with tooltip, right now I'm making tooltip. I'm changing css display property in order to make it visible or not during mouse enter and leave. But there is an error and I don't know what to do...

Here is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Style from 'style-it'; 
var Ink = require('react-ink');
import FontIcon from '../FontIcon/FontIcon';

var IconButton = React.createClass({ 

  getInitialState() {
      return {
          iconStyle: "",
          style: "",
          cursorPos: {},
      };
  },

  extend(obj, src) {
      Object.keys(src).forEach(function(key) { obj[key] = src[key]; });
      return obj;
  },

    Tooltip(props) {

        var style = {};

        if (this.tooltipDisplay) {
            style.display = "block";
        } else if (!this.tooltipDisplay) {
            style.display = "none";
        };

        return <div className="tooltip" style={style}>{_props.tooltip}</div>;
    },

    showTooltip(){
        this.tooltipDisplay = true;
    },

    removeTooltip(){
        this.tooltipDisplay = false;
    },

  render() {

    var _props = this.props,
      tooltip = this.Tooltip,
      opts,
      tooltipDisplay = false,
      disabled = false,
      rippleOpacity,
        outterStyleMy = {
        border: "none",
            outline: "none",
            padding: "8px 10px",
        "background-color": "red",
        "border-radius": 100 + "%",
        cursor: "pointer",
        },
        iconStyleMy = {
            "font-size": 12 + "px",
            "text-decoration": "none",
            "text-align": "center",
            display: 'flex',
            'justify-content': 'center',
            'align-items': 'center',
        },
      rippleStyle = {
        color: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
      };

    if (_props.disabled || _props.disableTouchRipple) {
      rippleStyle.opacity = 0;
    };

    this.setState({
      iconStyle: _props.iconStyle
    });

    this.setState({
      style: _props.style
    });

    if (_props.disabled) {
       disabled = true;
    };

    if (this.state.labelStyle) {
        iconStyleMy = this.state.iconStyle;
    };

    if (this.state.style) {
      outterStyleMy = this.state.style;
    };

    if (_props.href) {
      opts.href = _props.href;
    };

        var buttonStyle = this.extend(outterStyleMy, iconStyleMy);

        return(
        <Style>
        {`
          .IconButton{
            position: relative;
          }
          .IconButton:disabled{
            color: ${_props.disabledColor};
          }
          .btnhref{
            text-decoration: none;
          }
        `}
         <a {...opts} className="btnhref" > 
          <tooltip text={this.props.tooltip} position={this.options} />
          <button ref="button" className={"IconButton" + _props.className} disabled={disabled} style={buttonStyle}
          onMouseEnter={this.showTooltip} onMouseLeave={this.removeTooltip} >
            <Ink background={true} style={rippleStyle} opacity={rippleOpacity} />
            <FontIcon className={_props.iconClassName}/>
          </button>
        </a>
        </Style>
        );

  }
});



ReactDOM.render(
 <IconButton href="" className="" iconStyle="" style="" iconClassName="face" disabled="" disableTouchRipple="" tooltip="aaaaa" />,
 document.getElementById('app')
);
```

In console I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at defineRefPropWarningGetter (App.js:1053)
at Object.ReactElement.createElement (App.js:1220)
at Object.createElement (App.js:3329)
at Constructor.render (App.js:43403)
at App.js:15952
at measureLifeCyclePerf (App.js:15233)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (App.js:15951)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (App.js:15978)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._updateRenderedComponent (App.js:15902)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._performComponentUpdate (App.js:15880)
```

I can't find out what's wrong. I know it might be something about calling a function which in turn calls another function. But I can't see anything like this in my code and I'm not sure if it's all about it. Thanks for help :)

Comment: Never, ever, under any circumstance... I don't care what you might come up for for reasoning... do not ever call `setState` from inside your `render` function ;) Calling `setState` causes a rerender, which causes `setState` to be called which causes a rerender, which then calls `setState` and thus causes a rerender, which then calls `setState` yet agian, and your component gets rerendered, then `setState` is called again and another rerender... until your call stack is max'd out

Comment: @RyanWheale I wish I could upvote that comment a million times :)

Comment: @RyanWheale, how to call setState outside render?

Comment: @RyanWheale i wish i could upvote your comment forever. Although the question remains how we do setState outside the render. Though i have noticed when i set the property, the state value remains persistent without calling the setState in render method.

Comment: `setState` should only happen in two different situations: 1) during construction when the component is first instantiated, and 2) after the user does something. If this isn't clear to you, then open an issue with example code and someone can show you how to manage state.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The problem is you are calling `setState` from inside your render function. State changes should only happen as a result of something changing: user clicked on a button, the browser window was resized, a picture was taken, etc.

> Never ever ever ever update the state while rendering (repeat that last sentence 20 times and never forget it).

Here is the problem code:

```
render () {
    ...
    this.setState({
      iconStyle: _props.iconStyle
    });

    this.setState({
      style: _props.style
    });
    ...
}
```

The above code would cause an infinite loop of sorts because `setState` causes `render` to be called. Since `iconStyle` and `style` are props, and props cannot change, you should use those props to build your initial state.

```
getInitialState() {
  return {
      iconStyle: this.props.iconStyle,
      style: this.props.style,
      cursorPos: {},
  };
}
```

Later, if someone clicks a button and you want the iconStyle to change, you would create a click handler which updates your state:

```
handleClick () {
  this.setState({
    iconStyle: 'clicked'
  });
}
```

This would cause your component to be rerendered and the new state would be reflected.

Think of your "state" as someone cooking and we are going to take photographs of them cooking. The **initial state** is "eggs cracked: **no**, flour poured: **no**, veggies chopped: **no**", and you take a picture of this state. Then the chef does something - cracks the eggs. The state has now changed, and you take a picture of it. Then she cuts the veggies. Again, the state has changed and you take a picture.

Each photograph in the analogy represents your "render" function - a snapshot of the "state" at a particular point in time. If every time you took a photograph the flour got poured, well we would have to take another picture because the flour was just poured. Taking another picture would cause more flour to get poured so we'd have to take another picture. Eventually you'd fill the kitchen to the ceiling with a celiac's nightmare and suffocate everybody in the room. You'd also run out of film or hard disk space on your camera.

Comment: That's great, thanks. But now I', getting this errors:   1) Warning: Unknown prop `text` on <tooltip> tag. Remove this prop from the element.       2)Warning: Unsupported style property background-color. Did you mean backgroundColor? Check the render method of `IconButton`.   Those weren't there before

Comment: Those a separate issues but should be easy to debug. I'm not sure about the "text" prop - it doesn't look like you're using it. Also, styles in react must use the javascript name. Basically `background-color` becomes `backgroundColor`, `border-width` becomes `borderWidth` etc. This is normal react stuff.

Comment: Another hint I'll give you is that the visibility of your tooltip should be part of your state. Initially, tooltipIsVisible should be false. When the user clicks the button, you should call setState and set the value to true. Doing so will cause your component to be rerendered. Inside your `render` function you would check this variable and render the tooltip accordingly.

Comment: I know, but I wanted to try this, because that with state wasn't working because of issue above and I didn't know what's going on. But with styles, before I had in object like this "background-color": "red" and it was ok so why now it's not?

Comment: Not really sure - I can't really see your app. I'm just trying to give you tips on how to property use react. I suggest taking a couple steps back and learning a little more about the tools you are using. You can read about [css styles here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#style), and I generally suggest you read through all of [the react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/hello-world.html) - take about an hour and read through it.

Comment: I know this question is way old, but...  I've heard one should not set state from props.  Although, it seems like the best solution at times, I've avoided it because of the suggestions that props and state should be separate.  Are there cases where it is acceptable?

Comment: @mojave You shouldn't just blindly copy props onto state (eg.`this.state = Object.assign({}, props)`). That is bad practice. But it's perfectly normal to use props to create your initial state. I usually name those props something like `initialColor`, `intialCount`, etc

Answer (score 11):

Thanks to @RyanWheale I noticed my mistake.

In my render function I was returning a button element which called a function which changed a certain state. The returned button looked like this:

```
<button onclick={this.edit()} className="button-primary">Edit</button>
```

And my `edit` function changes some state and looks like this:

```
edit: function () {
    this.setState({editing: true});
}
```

So, I my mistake is that I, accidentally, typed the parenthesis after `this.edit`. So, when the button element was being rendered, the edit function was actually called and chaos happened. Now, when I wrote

`<button onclick={this.edit} className="button-primary">Edit</button>`

instead of

`<button onclick={this.edit()} className="button-primary">Edit</button>`

it worked flawlessly.
I hope I help someone save hours of his precious life.

Cheers :)

Comment: Ah, this is essentially the same thing as calling `setState` from inside a render function. Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem, I had installed "reactime" extension and that extension caused me this problem. Removing that extension from my chrome, solved the issue.

Comment: reactime did the worst!

Answer (score 1):

I  got 'Maximum call stack size exceeded', and similar errors because of framer-motion API dependency, version bigger than 4.1.17 (today's version is 5.5.5). I don't figured out why yet.
For the same extensions also, got  some weird errors like 'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated, and similar bugs.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30652791)

Comment: The main point is that these or similar mistakes that cost us hundreds of times, and come from "reactime" or "framer-motion"(irrelevant). It is obvious that many mistakes of this type often come exactly from some kind of 3rd party extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in my SPFX project while running Gulp Serve. I deleted the newly added reference in my config.json file and it worked.

More details: https://fixingsharepoint.blogspot.com/2022/04/rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size.html