# maximum call stack size exceeded when rendering webcam video to canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, webrtc

I am developing an app where there will be two participant in a session and they can have video call. Basically, there will be 3 video stream. Two of the participants and one will be shared screen. This part is already working but when user clicks on record button, those 3 video should be fed in canvas and when paused then it should be paused. I am trying to render only one video in canvas for testing if it work `"RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded on draw function ".`

```
const draw = (canva, context) => {
    console.log('localVideoRef', localVideoRef)
    context.drawImage(localVideoRef.current, 0, 0, canva.clientWidth, canva.clientHeight);
    console.log('context draw', context)
    requestAnimationFrame(draw(canva, context))
  }
  const handleRecord = () => {
    const canva = document.createElement('canvas');
    canva.id = "canvas";
    const context = canva.getContext("2d");
    canva.width = canva.clientWidth;
    canva.width = canva.clientHeight;
    console.log('canva', context, canva);
    console.log('room', room);
    draw(canva, context);
    requestAnimationFrame(draw(canva, context)) # above error is shown here
    console.log('canva after drawing image', canva);
  }
```

The error is in this line `requestAnimationFrame(draw(canva, context))`

Update(still continuously runs even after stopping the record)

```
let canva, context = null;

function App(props) {
  const [record, setRecord] = React.useState('');
  React.useEffect(() => {
    canva = document.createElement('canvas');
    canva.id = "canvas";
    context = canva.getContext("2d");
    canva.width = canva.clientWidth;
    canva.width = canva.clientHeight;
  }, [])
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('record', record);
    if (record === 'start' || record === 'resume') {
      requestAnimationFrame(() => draw(canva, context));
      console.log('canva after paint video', canva);
    } else {
      // when pausing or stoping recording, the painting should not be done. 
      console.log('this is the canva after paused or stopped', canva)
    }

  }, [record])
  const draw = (canva, context) => {
    context.drawImage(localMediaRef.current, 0, 0, canva.clientWidth, canva.clientHeight);
    console.log('painting');
    requestAnimationFrame(() => draw(canva, context));
  }
  const handleRecord = (type) => {
    setRecord(type)
  }
  render {
    return (

    )
  }
}
```

Comment: May help you. found in the stack overlow
[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41229332/react-uncaught-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded)

Answer (score 3):

```
requestAnimationFrame(draw(canva, context))
```

This code will *immediately* call draw, and then whatever the return value of draw is will be passed into requestAnimationFrame. Inside of draw, you repeat this process, immediately calling draw, which immediately calls draw, etc.

Instead, you want to pass a function into request animation frame, like this:

```
requestAnimationFrame(() => draw(canva, context));
```

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but i dont think the return value of draw is passed into `requestAnimationFrame`? According to the docs, the syntax is `window.requestAnimationFrame(callback);`. The callback (which is passed to the function) is  *"The function to call when it's time to update your animation for the next repaint."*, not it's return value?

Comment: but why does it still paints when i stop the record.

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is because you are **already** calling the `requestAnimationFrame()` in your `draw()` code. Hence the function is already recursive. By calling `draw` AND `requestAnimationFrame(draw)`, you are calling 2 infinitely recursive functions at once. Simply remove the `draw()` and it will work:

```
const draw = (canva, context) => {
    console.log('localVideoRef', localVideoRef)
    context.drawImage(localVideoRef.current, 0, 0, canva.clientWidth, canva.clientHeight);
    console.log('context draw', context)
    requestAnimationFrame( (timestamp)=>draw(canva, context) ); // EDITED AS PER @Nicholas' answer.
}
const handleRecord = () => {
    const canva = document.createElement('canvas');
    canva.id = "canvas";
    const context = canva.getContext("2d");
    canva.width = canva.clientWidth;
    canva.width = canva.clientHeight;
    console.log('canva', context, canva);
    console.log('room', room);
    //draw(canva, context);        //just remove this line
    requestAnimationFrame( (timestamp)=>draw(canva, context) ) // EDITED AS PER @Nicholas' answer.
    console.log('canva after drawing image', canva);
}
```

Check out this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) for more details on `requestAnimationFrame`. Notice that in their eg, `requestAnimationFrame(step)` is called, but `step()` is not called.

**Update:**
As @Nicholas pointed out, you need to wrap your draw function in another function. This is shown above.

As for *why* it causes a `maximum call size exceeded` error, I'm actually a bit confused. When I tested the faulty code on Chrome console, I got this error instead:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'requestAnimationFrame' on 'Window': The callback provided as parameter 1 is not a function.

This is actually correct in theory. Think of `requestAnimationFrame` as something similar to `setTimeout`. `setTimeout` uses a callback like `setTimeout(callback, time);`; so does `requestAnimationFrame`.

When you pass `requestAnimationFrame( draw(canva, context) )`, you are basically telling the requestAnimationFrame function to do something like **`draw(canva, context)()`** somewhere in its code, not **`draw(canva, context)`** as (I think) you are expecting. Hence it throws the `callback provided is not a function` error on my Chrome console.

But as for **`max call stack exceeded`** error, I think your JavaScript Engine/compiler's `requestAnimationFrame` catches the error, ignores it, and **then proceeds to call the draw function as is**. This thus translates basically to:

```
draw = (canva, context)=>{
    ...
    draw(canva, context) //oh noes
}
```

This is basically now an **infinitely running recursive function**. 
Hence, `maximum call stack exceeded` error.

Comment: It's true that they have an extra call to draw, but that's not the reason they're overflowing the call stack.

Comment: @NicholasTower you are indeed right that this is not the reason for the overflowed call stack.

Comment: @NicholasTower I have made a theory as to why it's overflowing the call stack. It's not as simple as wrapping the function, because by right it should throw a `callback provided is not a function` error, as it did in my console