# changing state with Styled Components -> React, Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components, react-state-management, react-state

I have a button that shows a panel when it is clicked, and hides it when the panel is clicked

The code, that works as expected

```js
const Loged = () => {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(0)
  const input_id = React.createRef()
  const input_pass = React.createRef()

  return (
    <MenuLogin modal={modal}>
      <div
        onClick={e => {
          e.stopPropagation()
          setModal(1)
        }}
      >
        Click Me
      </div>

      <div
        onClick={e => {
          e.stopPropagation()
          setModal(0)
        }}
      >
        <div onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>
          <input ref={input_id} onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()} placeholder="id" type="text" />
          <input ref={input_pass} onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()} placeholder="password" type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </MenuLogin>
  )
}
```

Where `MenuLogin` is a styled component

```js
const MenuLogin = styled.div`
  & > div:last-child {
    visibility: ${props => (props.modal ? 'visible' : 'hidden')};
    opacity: ${props => (props.modal ? '1' : '0')};
  }
`
```

However, now I want to use `setModal` outside of this component, so what I do is to move the `const [modal, setModal] = useState(0)` to the parent element and pass these variables as parameters

So that now I have

```js
const Loged = (modal, setModal) => {
...
}
```

With the parent code like this

```js
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(0)
  return (<ChildComponent modal={modal} setModal={setModal} />)
}
```

But now, when I try to hide the element (`setModal(0)`) from the same place (within the child component) I get the 
`React, Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

If I do something like

```js
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(0)
  const changeState = (s) => setModal(s)
  return (<ChildComponent modal={modal} setModal={changeState} />)
}
```

I can click two times extra before I get the error (??)

Reading [React, Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41229332/react-uncaught-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded) I'd say I'm doing something conceptually wrong here, but cannot find what is it

EDIT:
I can see that this should work (see [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/usestate-01-9pybd))
So my suspect is the Styled Component that somehow causes a loop?

Comment: Please share parent code

Comment: @Siya I've added it, but it doesn't add much (this is only the relevant part of the code)

Comment: @Siya I've seen that this should work (see the codesandbox), so I guess the problem is with the styled component somehow?

Answer (score 0):

your same code looks working fine with styled components 
https://codesandbox.io/s/usestate-01-o791y

Comment: Indeed it works, I've redone it to a code closer to mine and it works https://codesandbox.io/s/usestate-01-eo75b but in my local code this is the cause of the error, so I'm confused right now

Comment: @GWorking Maybe you can check you styled component version

Comment: Just done and it still works (in codesandbox and same react and styled versions I have in local), I'm using gatsby and many other packages here, seems like a nightmare to find anything, don't really know what to do now

Comment: Somehow I see that with the parent component having different child components, if I eliminate some of them then the error disappears, but it doesn't seem it is one in particular, but that like there were too many, does it make any sense?

Comment: Check if any of that child components using state in the render function, that usually cause this issues

Comment: No one, and it doesn't make any sense, the error disappears if I eliminate elements that doesn't have any special code nor use the state. For example, I can eliminate a part of the SEO with react-helmet and it completely works, or I can eliminate all the other parts and leave only the code of the question and the SEO part and it completely works, but if I leave the SEO part, the code of the question, and a third nonsense element then it fails again

Comment: At the end, it is something related to gatsby-themes, since if I move a child element that is inherited from the parent theme, to the same place as the child theme, there is no error