# reactjs contact form with nodemailer and firebase functions - RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I think I'm at the last step of almost having a contact-me form set up but I can't seem to get it. I have another form set up similarly, although it doesn't deal with firebase functions in it. I've been looking at a couple of tutorials to see how I might be able to fix it but no luck.

For the curious, these are the ones I've been looking at:

1. https://pantaley.com/blog/How-to-integrate-Serverless-contact-form-using-Firebase-Cloud-functions-in-React/
2. https://betterprogramming.pub/a-simple-and-easy-contact-form-step-by-step-tutorial-react-js-1532bc025980
3. https://academind.com/tutorials/sending-an-email-with-react-and-cloud-functions/ <-- my favorite

I have the code set up in my firebase functions index.js and I have tested it with postman and it is successful. so I know the index.js code works.

but when I try to create the "contact-us" page with the code posted below labeled "original code" and click on the "send" button I've created, nothing happens and I see this error in the console when I inspect.

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at FiberNode.hasOwnProperty (<anonymous>)
    at mapValues (serializer.ts:29)
    at Serializer.encode (serializer.ts:61)
    at serializer.ts:61
    at mapValues (serializer.ts:30)
    at Serializer.encode (serializer.ts:61)
    at serializer.ts:61
<error repeats>
```

here is my code for my contact form. When I step through, it hangs up here

```
sendEmail({
   name: nameRef,
   email: emailRef,
   message: messageRef
})
```

Original code
`contactUs.js`

```
import React, {useRef, useState} from "react";
import {useAuth} from "../contexts/AuthContext";
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom";
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import classes from "./xclasses.module.scss";
import {Button, Container, Form} from "react-bootstrap";

const sendEmail = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('sendEmail');

export default function ContactUs() {
    const nameRef = useRef();
    const emailRef = useRef();
    const messageRef = useRef();
    const firmRef = useRef();
    const history = useHistory();

    const [error, setError] = useState("")
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
```

What I've tried:

I  tried moving the sendEmail call outside of the handleSubmit on its own because of this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41229332/react-uncaught-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded) saying to not call a setState call inside the render call basically because it performs an infinite loop.

The form clears after the submit button is clicked because of the history.push("/ContactUs") call, but the email is not sent and I can see no sendMail called on my firebase functions dashboard.

Try B Code

```
    const submitForm = async () => {
        await sendEmail({
            name: nameRef,
            email: emailRef,
            message: messageRef
        }).then(result => {
            console.log("contact-us message sent with " + result.data.message)        
        })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);               
            });
    }*/
```

Original Code

```
    async function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        setError("")
        setLoading(true)

       sendEmail({
            name: nameRef,
            email: emailRef,
            message: messageRef
        }).then(result => {
            console.log("contact-us message sent with " + result.data.message)            
        })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);                
            });

        history.push("/ContactUs")
        setLoading(false)
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className={classes.body}>
                <Container>
                    <div className={classes.body}>
                        <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                        {/*<Form onSubmit={submitForm}>*/} // also tried this (Try B Code)
                        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                            <Form.Group id="email">
                                <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control type="email" ref={emailRef} required/>
                            </Form.Group>
                            <Form.Group id="name">
                                <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control type="text" ref={nameRef} required/>
                            </Form.Group>
                            <Form.Group id="message">
                                <Form.Label>Message</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control type="text" ref={messageRef} required/>
                            </Form.Group>

                            <Form.Group id="firm">
                                <Form.Label>Firm</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control type="text" ref={firmRef} required/>
                            </Form.Group>

                            {/*<Button onClick={submitForm} className="w-100" type="submit">*/}
                            // also tried this ^^ (Try B Code)
                            <Button disabled={loading} className="w-100" type="submit">
                                Send
                            </Button>
                        </Form>
                    </div>
                </Container>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

**Update on 2021/05/16 from @somoneSpecial comments**

Updated code:

```
import React, {useRef, useState} from "react";
import {useAuth} from "../contexts/AuthContext";
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom";
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import classes from "./SyncManagerDemo.module.scss";
import {Button, Container, Form} from "react-bootstrap";


export default function ContactUs() {
    const nameRef = useRef();
    const emailRef = useRef();
    const messageRef = useRef();
    const firmRef = useRef();
    const history = useHistory();

    const [error, setError] = useState("")
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)


    async function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        const sendEmail = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('sendEmail');
        console.log("nameRef: " + nameRef.current.value);
        console.log("emailRef: " + emailRef.current.value);
        console.log("messageRef: " + messageRef.current.value);

        const test = await sendEmail({
            name: nameRef.current.value,
            email: emailRef.current.value,
            message: messageRef.current.value
        }).then(function (result) {
            var messageSent = result.data.message;
            console.log(nameRef.current + " " + emailRef.current + " " + messageRef.current + " " + messageSent)
        });        
    }
return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className={classes.body}>
                <Container>
                    <div className={classes.body}>
                        <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                        {/*todo: convert to Bootstrap inputs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/ */}
                        {/*<Form onSubmit={submitForm}>*/}
                        {/*<Form onSubmit={sendEmail}>*/}
                        {/*<Form onSubmit={sendEmail2}>*/}
                        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                            <Form.Group id="email">
                                <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control type="email" ref={emailRef} required/>
                            </Form.Group>
                            <Form.Group id="name">
                                <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control type="text" ref={nameRef} required/>
                            </Form.Group>
                            <Form.Group id="message">
                                <Form.Label>Message</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control type="text" ref={messageRef} required/>
                            </Form.Group>

                            <Form.Group id="firm">
                                <Form.Label>Firm</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control type="text" ref={firmRef} required/>
                            </Form.Group>

                            {/*<Button onClick={submitForm} className="w-100" type="submit">*/}
                            <Button disabled={loading} className="w-100" type="submit">
                                Send
                            </Button>
                        </Form>
                    </div>
                </Container>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

am now getting error of:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: internal
HttpsErrorImpl                          error.ts:65
_errorForResponse                       error.ts:175
(anonymous function)                    service.ts:276
step                                    tslib.es6.js:100
(anonymous function)                    tslib.es6.js:81
fulfilled                               tslib.es6.js:71
Async call from async function
handleSubmit                            ContactUs.js:47
callCallback                            react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev                react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback                   react-dom.development.js:4056
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError react-dom.development.js:4070
executeDispatch                         react-dom.development.js:8243
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder        react-dom.development.js:8275
processDispatchQueue                    react-dom.development.js:8288
dispatchEventsForPlugins                react-dom.development.js:8299
(anonymous function)                    react-dom.development.js:8508
batchedEventUpdates$1                   react-dom.development.js:22396
batchedEventUpdates                     react-dom.development.js:3745
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem       react-dom.development.js:8507
attemptToDispatchEvent                  react-dom.development.js:6005
dispatchEvent                           react-dom.development.js:5924
unstable_runWithPriority                scheduler.development.js:646
runWithPriority$1                       react-dom.development.js:11276
discreteUpdates$1                       react-dom.development.js:22413
discreteUpdates                         react-dom.development.js:3756
dispatchDiscreteEvent                   react-dom.development.js:5889
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I do not know what causes the error but i'm quite sure this function has error.

```
sendEmail({
        name: nameRef.current.value,
        email: emailRef.current.value,
        message: messageRef.current.value
    }).then(result => {
        console.log("contact-us message sent with " + result.data.message)            
    })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);                
        });

    history.push("/ContactUs") //<=== this is being called before sendMail is completed.
    setLoading(false)
```

You should probably try this code instead.

```
   try {
     const results = await sendEmail({
            name: nameRef.current.value,
            email: emailRef.current.value,
            message: messageRef.current.value
        })
    console.log("contact-us message sent with " + result.data.message)  
    setLoading(false)
    history.push("/ContactUs") //<-- now this will be called properly.
    } catch (err) {
       console.log('error', error)
    }
```

Another problem is your ref, you got to use ref.current instead of just ref. See `sendEmail`

#### Firebase Functions

Since you are using `firebase.functions().httpsCallable`, make sure you are `.onCall()` instead of `onRequest().`

Comment: I tried your suggestion inside of my `async function handleSubmit(e)` and still got the same error. seems to get hung up on the `const result =` line.

Comment: update answer. should be using nameRef.current rather than just nameRef. Kindly  console.log all your ref to make sure you are getting the values you want (strings) before you submit via sendMail

Comment: @somoneSpecial, I've updated my post and now showing the new error. good call on console logging the refs. I had to end up doing `ref.current.value` to get the values that I wanted. If i just do `ref.current`, i get `[object HTMLInputElement]` in the console.

Comment: You may have to create a new question, your new error seems to derive from your google functions. At the same time, can you catch the error from your sendmail function call?

Comment: In your firebase functions did you use .onRequest or .onCall?

Comment: its an `.onRequest` call. I'll make another question and then place a link here

Comment: you should be using `.onCall` since you are using `httpsCallable`. Please checkout how to write the return values for httpCallable functions - https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

Comment: well played. That's probably it. I'm looking into it. if you want to post this as an answer, I can mark it correct to give credit.

Comment: ended up making some headway and creating another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67575726/reactjs-not-calling-firebase-function-nodemailer)