# Reactjs not calling Firebase function Nodemailer

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've created a contact form in ReactJS and am trying to send an email to myself using [Nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) with firebase functions. The email will consist of whatever the person has filled out in the contact form.

I have tried the firebase function using postman and it works, I successfully receive an email when the endpoint is tried.

However when I try to call it in my React app, nothing is sent, and there are no errors reported. I have looked online to see what I am doing wrong but no luck.

Here is my code.

firebase functions `index.js`

```
// import needed modules
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const office365Email = functions.config().outlook365.email;
const office365Password = functions.config().outlook365.password;

// create and config transporter
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtp.office365.com",
  port: 587,
  secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
  auth: {
    user: office365Email,
    pass: office365Password,
  },
});

// export the cloud function called `sendEmail`
exports.sendEmail = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

  // for testing purposes
  console.log(
      "from sendEmail function. The request object is:",
      JSON.stringify(data.body)
  );

    const email = data.email;
    const name = data.name;
    const message = data.message;


    // config the email message
    const mailOptions = {
      from: email,
      to: office365Email,
      subject: "New message from the nodemailer-form app",
      text: `${name} says: ${message}`,
    };


    return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions).then(() => {  
        return { success: true };
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

here is my reactjs code:

```
import React, {useRef, useState} from "react";
import {useAuth} from "../contexts/AuthContext";
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom";
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import classes from "./SyncManagerDemo.module.scss";
import {Button, Container, Form} from "react-bootstrap";


export default function ContactUs() {
    const nameRef = useRef();
    const emailRef = useRef();
    const messageRef = useRef();
    const firmRef = useRef();
    const history = useHistory();

    const [error, setError] = useState("")
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

    const sendEmail = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('sendEmail');

    async function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        
        console.log("nameRef: " + nameRef.current.value);
        console.log("emailRef: " + emailRef.current.value);
        console.log("messageRef: " + messageRef.current.value);

        return /*const test =*/ await sendEmail({
            name: nameRef.current.value,
            email: emailRef.current.value,
            message: messageRef.current.value
        }).then(result => {
            
            return console.log("message sent");
            
            }).catch(error => {  
          
                console.log("error occurred.");
                return console.log(error);            
        });

    }
    
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className={classes.body}>
                <Container>
                    <div className={classes.body}>
                        <h2>Contact Us</h2>                        
                        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                            <Form.Group id="email">
                                <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control type="email" ref={emailRef} required/>
                            </Form.Group>
                            <Form.Group id="name">
                                <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control type="text" ref={nameRef} required/>
                            </Form.Group>
                            <Form.Group id="message">
                                <Form.Label>Message</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control type="text" ref={messageRef} required/>
                            </Form.Group>

                            <Form.Group id="firm">
                                <Form.Label>Firm</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control type="text" ref={firmRef} required/>
                            </Form.Group>                            
                            <Button disabled={loading} className="w-100" type="submit">
                                Send
                            </Button>
                        </Form>
                    </div>
                </Container>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
```

not sure if this helps but my postman POST request body I send through looks like this which works:

```
{
    "data": {
                "email": "my email@email.com",
                "name": "test name",
                "message": "hello world"
            }
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: No errors in the logs??

Comment: nope. it shows `message sent` at the end after my `console.log(refs)`

Comment: can u share your firebase initialisation codes

Comment: I was able to get it. it had to do with the `from` email I was using. The `from` email should have been my outlook365 email. An error was showing in the firebase console which I was mistakenly not checking. The From email has to match your config email I believe. So in this case, the last image showing the `data` should have had the outlook365 email. The `To` email can be changed to whatever you want.